# Can't Access Routerlogin.Net With Netgear Router

Tags: router

I'm using Netgear WNDR4500 with Timewarner Cable. Now i can't go to routerlogin.net to update firmware ( trying [http://192.168.0.1](http://www.192168o1Login.pw) or 192.168.1.1 ) I still surf internet with no problem. Who has experience with this situation please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that 192.168.0.1 (or 1.1) is the IP of your router? Open up a command prompt and type in "ipconfig" and then look for "Default Gateway". If you are correct it should say: 192.168.0.1 (or 192.168.1.1)

Then open your browser, type in "192.168.0.1" and try to connect. If that does not work please tell us what happened and what your browser is telling you at that point.